# Modify Taskbar layout for Windows 10 v.1607 on desktop pc

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I recently updated Windows 10 to Ver. 1607 (build 14393.187) and have a few issues with how my taskbar looks.

1. It now has a vertical scrollbar, This scroll bar/button stacks the open apps and those I want for quick launching. Can I remove the scroll  bar/button?
2. I also don't like that the taskbar is overtaken by the list of desktop icons. I would like to remove the '>>' button that is just to the left of the notification area, simply removing the desktop icons.

I have spent almost an entire day looking for help to fix/customize the Windows 10 taskbar on a desktop pc installation. I'm finding a lot pertaining to tablets settings that do not pertain to me. Also, the settings interface changes for different versions of Windows 10 and recommended settings do not pertain across the versions. Pretty sure others are disappointed with this too.

*** Update Since Posted ***
I found the Taskbar had gotten locked. Unlocking let me push the border to the right so that now only one desktop folder icon is visible. I would prefer none be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have toolbars showing, and they're adjusted to take up most of your Taskbar area.

For your scrollbar issue, you need to enlarge the area for the running/pinned applications so they don't wrap to a new line once it fills the area (causing the scrollbar to show):

- Right-click the Taskbar.
- Uncheck "Lock the Taskbar" (if it's check marked).
- Click the columns of dots to the left of any showing toolbar (probably the "Desktop" toolbar judging by info supplied) and drag it to the left to expand the area available for application icons.

To remove the "Desktop »" toolbar from the taskbar completely:

- Right-click the Taskbar.
- Select "Toolbars"
- Uncheck "Desktop".

All the Windows 10 TaskBar customization info you'd need for this (and more) is readily available, so I'm confused why you had a hard time finding it.  For example, [this CNet article](https://www.cnet.com/au/how-to/10-ways-to-customize-the-taskbar-in-windows-10/) covers what we've covered here, perhaps go check that one out?

Comment: Techie007 on the job fast and accurate! I went outside for a minute after I discovered I had Toolbar locked and fixed that. I came back in and Bam! Techie007 had nailed it 100% . Thank you!